# Reading on weighing scales at the equator of a moon in a tidally locked two-body system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, orbital-motion

I'm trying a made-up extension of [this](https://physicstasks.eu/930/spring-scale-on-the-pole-and-on-the-equator) problem. Consider the planet Mars and its moon Deimos, which can be approximated as meeting the following simplifying conditions:

- Both objects are perfect spheres
- The orbit of Deimos is a perfect circle around the centre of Mars, orbiting in its equatorial plane (zero inclination and zero eccentricity)
- The rotational axes of each objects are parallel (not sure what the technical term is...)
- Deimos orbits in 30 hours and 18 minutes, and is tidally locked to Mars

So, the situation looks like this.

[image]

The question is, if an astronaut of known mass $ m $ stands on weighing scales at point A (on the equator of Deimos, so that Mars is directly overhead appearing stationary), how can we predict the reading?

---

I am trying to figure out what forces are real and what forces are fictitious, if any. I do not have a good grasp on inertial reference frames which I think are important here. My attempt would be to say that, by resolving forces "vertically" (actually horizontally in the diagram above) on the astronaut at point A,

$$ \underbrace{\frac{GM_{M}m}{(d + R_{M})^2}}_{\substack{\text{gravitational} \\ \text{pull to Mars}}} + \underbrace{F_{\text{scales}}}_{\substack{\text{contact force on} \\ \text{weighing scales}}} + \underbrace{m R_{D} \omega ^2}_{\substack{\text{centrifugal force} \\ \text{from Deimos'} \\ \text{rotation}}} - \underbrace{\frac{GM_{D}m}{R_D^2}}_{\substack{\text{gravitational} \\ \text{pull to Deimos}}} = \underbrace{m (d + R_{M}) \omega ^2}_{\substack{\text{centripetal force} \\ \text{on astronaut to} \\ \text{stay in circular orbit} \\ \text{around Mars}}} $$

(subscript D = for Deimos; subscript M = for Mars)

Then, if the scales were calibrated on Earth in its gravitational field $ g $, the reading on the scales in kg would be

$$ m' = \frac{F_{\text{scales}}}{g} $$

Following that calculation through with the given numbers, I get:

$$ \frac{F_{\text{scales}}}{m} = 0.032498 \ \text{N kg}^{-1} \ \xrightarrow[g \ = \ 9.81 \text{ N kg}^{-1}]{\text{using}} \ m' = \frac{F_{\text{scales}}}{g} = 0.003313m \ \Rightarrow \ \frac{m}{m'} = 301.861 $$

So, you are just over 300 times lighter on Deimos than on Earth. Have I performed this calculation correctly? Thanks for any help in checking my understanding. **I am aware that some of the components in my force equation are negligibly small, but I'm more concerned with whether they should be included or not in the first place.**